# Is asynchronous in C# the same implementation as in F#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, f#

Is the asynchronous implementation in C# 4.5 exactly the same as in F# 2 in the way threads are used?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

They are different. The main difference is that C# uses standard .NET `Task<T>` to represent asynchronous computations while F# uses its own type called `Async<T>`.

More specifically, the key differences are:

- A C# async method creates a `Task<T>` that is immediately started (*hot task* model) while F# creates a computation that you have to start explicitly (*generator* model). This means that F# computations are easier to compose (you can write higher level abstractions).
- In F# you also get better control over how is the computation started. You can start a computation using `Async.Start` to start it in the background or `Async.StartImmediate` to start it on the current thread.
- F# asynchronous workflows support *cancellation* automatically, so you do not have to pass `CancellationToken` around.
- Perhaps another consequence of the first point is that F# async workflows also support tail-recursion, so you can write recursive workflows (this would not work easily in C#, but C# does not use this programming style)

I wrote a more detailed article about this topic: [Asynchronous C# and F# (II.): How do they differ?](http://tomasp.net/blog/async-csharp-differences.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how are threads used under the hood? Don Syme points out in his book 'Expert F#' that F# uses thread hopping. Is this the same for C# or are there some differences?

Comment: In F#, when you start on a thread with specific `SynchronizationContext` (i.e. the GUI thread) then the asynchronous computation jumps back to this `SynchronizationContext`. I could not find a documentation saying how this behaves in C#, but my experiments show that it behaves the same - that is, if you start `await`ing on a GUI thread, then the rest of your computation will run on th GUI thread (even if the computaiton you're awaiting runs the continuation on another thread).